# why we don't need to use volatile variable when using __syncthreads

Tags: cuda

Everything is in the question.
I understand why we need variables to be `volatile` when we are using `__threadfence_block` and its similar functions :

> Note that for this ordering guarantee to be true, the observing
>   threads must truly observe the memory and not cached versions of it;
>   this is ensured by using the volatile keyword as detailed in Volatile
>   Qualifier.

However I wonder why we do not need variable to be `volatile` when we are using `__syncthreads` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions), `__syncthreads()` is both an execution barrier **and** a memory fence:

> waits until all threads in the thread block have reached this point **and all global and shared memory accesses made by these threads prior to `__syncthreads()` are visible to all threads in the block**.

The memory fencing function (i.e. "visibility") "forces" all updates to shared and global memory to be visible to other threads.

I assume this is what you are asking about.  I don't think making blanket statements like "you don't need to use volatile when using `__syncthreads()`" is a sensible idea.  It will depend on the code.  But in some situations, for example the [classical parallel reduction](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf), using a `__syncthreads()` at every step in the block-wide reduction will mean that the shared memory used for such a reduction need not be marked with `volatile`.

Since `__syncthreads()` is both an execution barrier and a memory fence, there are certain statements we can make about `__syncthreads()` usage that would not be applicable to just usage of `__threadfence()` alone.

Suppose I have this code:

```
__global__ void k(int *data){
  ...
  *data = 1;
  __syncthreads();
  if (*data == 1){
    ...}
  ...
}
```

In this case, any thread in a particular block executing the if statement is guaranteed to see `*data` as 1.  There are two components to this:

1. `__syncthreads()` is a (device-wide) memory fence.  It forces any thread that has written the value, to make that value visible.  This effectively means, since this is a device-wide memory fence, that the value written at least has populated the L2 cache (which is a device-wide interposer to global memory, effectively a proxy for global memory).
2. `__syncthreads()` is a (threadblock-wide) execution barrier.  It forces all threads to reach at the barrier before any can proceed.  This execution ordering behavior means that by the time any thread executes the above if-statement, the guarantee in item 1 above is in effect.

Note that there is a subtle distinction here.  Other threads, in other blocks, at other points in the code, may or may not see the value written by a different block.

Only when we have combined execution synchronization and memory fencing, can we be certain that values populated by one thread are truly visible to another thread.  And without use of cooperative groups, CUDA provides no mechanism to synchronize execution across separate blocks.

`__threadfence()`, by itself, makes the value *eventually* visible, but without understanding relative order of execution between the writing thread and the reading thread, it's not possible to make guarantees just based on code inspection.

Likewise `volatile` guarantees something similar to `__threadfence()` (for the writing thread), but is also somewhat different.  `__threadfence()` guarantees that the writing thread will eventually push its data to the L2 (i.e. make it visible).  `volatile` does something similar, but also guarantees that a reading thread will not read a "stale copy" in L1 but will go to L2 (at least) to fetch the current value, any time a read of that value occurs in the code.

Note that there is never "invalidation" of L1 cache data triggered by device code activity on another SM.  `volatile` effectively guarantees that a load will bypass the L1.  `volatile` also guarantees that a store will go directly to the L2.  `__threadfence()` does something similar to the latter (at least by the point that the thread has proceeded beyond the `__threadfence()`), but makes no guarantees about L1 state in other SMs, or how threads in other SMs will read the value.

Comment: However, `__threadfence ` make the write only _available_ but not _visible_, that is why you need to have `volatile` variable?

Comment: I don't know what the difference would be between *available* and *visible*.  In english, to me, in this context, those words have quite similar meaning.  I'm also not sure what you're claiming in your question, or here.  It seems you think `volatile` is needed even if you are using `__threadfence()`.  I'm not sure that is the case.  Discussing these things in the abstract without a code example might not make sense.  A similar statement could be made about `__threadfence()` and `volatile`.  However `__threadfence_block()` as in your question only has block level visibility guarantee.

Comment: To me, available means that the cache is flush. Visible means that the cache is flushed and invalidated (I am using the wording from Vulkan).

On `https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions` it is wrote for `__threadfence` that volatile is needed `Note that for this ordering guarantee to be true, the observing threads must truly observe the memory and not cached versions of it; this is ensured by using the volatile keyword`. That is why I am misunderstanding some concepts... By the way, I agree that discussing things in the abstract is not easy ^^

Comment: Yes, I understand your question better now.  I've made some edits to my answer.  This is a fairly complex topic.

Comment: Note that in a multi-block scenario, `__syncthreads()` by itself, may or may not guarantee visibility to other blocks.  Unless you know the relative order of execution, it may be impossible to say.  Furthermore, `__syncthreads()` doesn't do anything about values cached in L1 in other SMs.  So `volatile` might be necessary, even with `__syncthreads()` depending on the exact reading and writing example.

Comment: I saw you worked at Nvidia, so maybe you can answer this question. In a GLSL shader, it is not necessary to make a variable volatile because you can make them coherent. Is there such a keyword in CUDA? Is there a lot of usecase that make volatile necessary in GLSL Shader?

Comment: Another question, if the `__syncthreads` make the writes visible to other threads, and since other thread will not read a _stale copy_  in L1, It is also an invalidation, no?

Comment: `__syncthreads()` pushes data to the L2.  In that sense it is visible.  But if another thread in another SM has a stale copy of the data in L1, it may still pick up the stale copy.  `__syncthreads()` does not invalidate in the L1 of other SMs (nothing does).

Comment: But `__syncthreads()` invalidate the L1 cache of its own SM, right?

Comment: L1 is a write-through cache, so a write to it of any kind makes the data in it coherent with respect to any further reads of that data by threads in that SM.  It's not clear to me that __syncthreads() would need to modify this behavior.

Comment: If L1 is a write-through cache, what does`__threadfence_block()` do according to cache semantic? It just perform an ordering to avoid b wrote before a? Because `__threadfence_block()`, in my understanding, does not push any data in L2 cache, right?

Comment: I don't think any of this is published. The semantics of these functions are defined in the programming guide.